# Визуализация движения молекул в unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать визуализацию трех агрегатных состояний: твердое тело, жидкость и газ. Молекулы должны быть внутри прозрачного контейнера, чтобы можно было наблюдать их движение при анимации  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XLezjzohcU).[image: молекулы внутри прозрачного контейнера]

Я новичок в Unity. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Декомпозируйте задачу и решайте по шагам. Нарисуйте в дизайнере контейнер с коллайдерами. Сделайте создание частиц. Задайте им импульсы первоначальные. Обработайте столкновения. И т.д.